# Drupal-add-css not responding

Tags: css, module, sass, drupal-7, compass-sass

I'm using the following code to include *javascript* and *css*:

```
if( $form['#node']->type == 'e_form' ){
    drupal_add_css( drupal_get_path('module', 'e_form') . '/css/stylesheets/screen.css' );
    drupal_add_js( drupal_get_path('module', 'e_form') . '/js/react.js', 'file' );
}
```

The javascript code loads but the css does not.

The css is compiled via **compass** from a SCSS file. Screen.css contains the resulting css code - so it all appears OK.

The module has the following structure:

```
.
├── css
│   ├── config.rb
│   ├── sass
│   │   ├── ie.scss
│   │   ├── print.scss
│   │   └── screen.scss
│   └── stylesheets
│       ├── ie.css
│       ├── print.css
│       └── screen.css
├── e_form.features.field_instance.inc
├── e_form.features.inc
├── e_form.info
├── e_form.module
├── e_form.strongarm.inc
└── js
    └── react.js
```

However, the styling does not take effect on the website. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not familiar with drupal but what if you need to also add a 3rd parameter, `, 'file'` > `drupal_add_css( drupal_get_path('module', 'e_form') . '/css/stylesheets/screen.css', 'file' );`

Comment: @Aziz: Thanks for responding. I already tried that and it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was not doing anything wrong - not really.

The issue is the name of the css script - **screen.css**. My guess is Drupal does not like multiple screen.css files even if they are located in different parts of the project.

I renamed my script as **style.css** and adjusted the code accordingly then my styling loaded as expected.